# Optimal model design for historical data tracking

Tags: django, django-models

How to construct relationships between these two models?

`Company` stores data about a company:

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    """Company related data"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    abbrev = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    founded = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

Meanwhile `StockQuote` tracks history of shares' prices:

```py
class StockQuote(models.Model):
    """Price history"""
    fetch_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
    business_day_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
    price = models.CharField(max_length=8, default='0.00')
```

Considering that each of `StockQuote` records can be assigned just one `Company`, how should these models be connected with relationships so that it would be straightforward to display all prices listed, querying just the `Company` model (API endpoint)?

Comment: With a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Coming out of the `StockQuote` model? Or the other way around?

Comment: yes from `StockQuote` to `Company`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Willem Van Onsem said, you just make a field in `StockQuote` as follows:

```
class StockQuote(models.Model):
    """Price history"""
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then from a `company` object you can simply do `company.stockquote_set.all()` to get a QuerySet of all stock-quotes that are related to that company.